# How to set hint for android Spinner with out using Spinner.setSeletion(0)

Tags: android, spinner

Can We add a hint to an Android spinner like EditText: hint, please send me any code. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put your array into a arraylist and write down

```
arraylist.add("whatever hint you want")
```

and then fill the spinner by this

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> ad_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arraylist);
                    ad_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    state.setAdapter(ad_state);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Android Spinner with Hint Sample project](https://github.com/ravivyas84/AndroidSpinnerHint)

override getview to display the hint before any value was selected.